# How do I use a constant in app-info.plist so that i am not hard coding stuff?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app-info.plist I have the following:

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb17372828282822</string>
            </array>
```

How do I change the number (fb17372828282822) to say something like:

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb{CONSTANT THAT HOLDS 17372828282822}</string>
            </array>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the build settings *Preprocess Info.plist File* and *Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File*.  If you need to avoid spaces between tokens, you can pass `-traditional` in the *Info.plist Other Preprocessor Flags* setting.